# MATLAB Data Retrieval from memory address?

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, mex

Apologies for the length of this post but we have a very specific scenario and I’d like to provide as much detail as possible.

We are attempting to write a MATLAB program to control and process data from a Newport FTIR Spectrometer for a research application. Our biggest hurdle is exporting the interferogram data array from the spectrometer’s proprietary software (MIRMAT Version 1.0, which was bundled with the instrument and which happens to be an old compiled Matlab program in .exe format) for use in our own program.

The MIRMAT software offers two ways of exporting the data we need. The first is manually saving the data in a .txt file, from which it can then be imported manually into our program. Unfortunately, this is not a viable option for us. We need to be able to pull several measurements rapidly within a second.

So that leaves us the latter option, which involves an ActiveX container with methods and properties that should allow us to access the data we need. These can be found in detail on pages 59 and 60 of the Spectrometer’s user’s manual, located here:

http://assets.newport.com/webDocumentsEN/images/Oriel%20FTIR%20User%20Manual.PDF

For our efforts thus far, we have relied on the ActiveX properties RawDataBuffer and Numberpoints to get the information we need to collect the desired data array (see below):

---

(*From the Newport Spectrometer User’s Manual Page 60*)

**long RawDataBuffer**:
pointer to the address in memory of an array of doubles containing the interferogram data array. (volts)

**long NumberPoints**:
the number of data points in the interferogram array

Given the pointer to memory and the number of data points as inputs, we attempted to write the following MATLAB executable (MEX) function to retrieve our desired data. The function is written in C++ and is compiled by MATLAB’s MEX features.

```
 /*=================================================================
   *      pass mem adress like this
   *      ptrArg = uint64(hex2dec( '00C2E4E8' ));
   *      myMexFile( ptrArg );
   *
   *      Execute Function like this:
   *      readArray2(uint64(g),n)
   *
   *      Where:
   *      g = RawDataBuffer value
   *      n = NumberPoints value
   *=================================================================*/
  #include "mex.h"


  void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray 
  *prhs[]) 
  {
      double  *pointer;          /* pointer to real data in new array */
      mwSize index;
      double *size;


      /* Check for proper number of arguments. */
      if (nrhs != 2) 
   { 
      mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "MATLAB:yprime:invalidNumInputs","Two input 
      arguments required.");
  }
      size = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
      uint64_T mlData = *static_cast<unsigned long long *>( mxGetData( 
      prhs[0] ) );

      double *p = reinterpret_cast<double *>( mlData );

      /* Create an m-by-n mxArray; you will copy existing data into it */
      plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, *size, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
      pointer = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

      /* Copy data into the mxArray */
      for ( index = 0; index < *size; index++ )
      {
          pointer[index] = p[index];
      }
      return;
  }
```

Unfortunately, this function does not return the data we need. It currently returns an array in which all the data points are zero. When we ready the memory location from the ActiveX contain we cast it and make sure that Matlab saves it as a UINT64. In short, we’re stumped. If our code can be fixed/improved, or if anyone has any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function you are showing in mex does nothing? It has 2 inputs and you copy the input to the output? What do you expect to happen? Ther eis no mention of `RawDataBuffer` nor `NumberPoints` in your code. You are literally doing nothing, and well, nothing happens

Comment: Well there is cenrainly something worng when you catch the pointer, or perhasp on those casts that you force there

Comment: @AnderBiguri - We are using the RawDataBuffer and NumberPoints properties outside of the above code to acquire the 2 input values we need. We retrieve them in matlab with the following commands: h = actxcontrol('FTSAX.FTSAXCrtl.1'); g = uint64(h.get.RawDataBuffer); n = uint32(h.get.NumberPoints); We then pass "g" and "n" into the MEX Function you see above as inputs. The current output of this code is an array with the correct number of data points ("n"), but all filled with zeroes. No real data.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - And yeah that's what we figured.